# Create generic requests class

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, request

I want to make a generic requests class for android

```
public class Requests {

    protected JSONObject postRequest(URL url, Map data) {

        return null;

    }

    protected JSONObject getRequest(URL url) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I know that if I want to do a request I must do a background task (Thread or AsyncTask),
but It´s posible to make a asynctask in both methods?, should I use Threads?, a better idea?
Thanks!

Comment: try [this, the Android Volley library](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728)

Comment: I appreciate it, it´s not a bad idea, but it´s so wide, I want something more simple

Comment: Will you have a set of sequential requests to handle, or will you have a queue of items that you want to process in parallel (with some maximum number in parallel at a time)?

Comment: Sequential requests only